# How to enable Javascript to control Phonegap Childbrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, childbrowser

I use the Phonegap Childbrowser for oAuth 2.0 authentication. After the authentication, I want to use Javascript in the web page to hide the Childbrowser without pressing the "done" button. How to do that?

For example, after authentication, we always get some callback parameters. That means our authentication is successful. At this time, we should close our browser, and I want to close the browser by Javascript without pressing any buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Capture `onLocationChange` on `childBrowser` and check the `url` parameter to see if it contains what you're looking for. If so, call `childBrowser.close()`.

One weirdness of ChildBrowser is that it doesn't have a `.clear()` method, so I've created a page called `nothing.html` that is blank. If you don't, you'll briefly see your auth page the next time you use ChildBrowser. This doubles as my `redirectUrl` for Facebook and Twitter auth. So when it gets to that page, I know it's time to close.

```
var URL_NOTHING = 'nothing.html';
window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function ( url ) {
    if ( url.indexOf( URL_NOTHING ) > -1 ) {
        if ( url.indexOf( 'oauth_token' ) > -1 ) { //twitter
            window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            //do twittery stuff
        } else { //facebook
            window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            //do facebooky stuff
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) plugin has a `close()` method to close the window from javascript code.

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
```